# French and lxml text

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying to assign a valid French text string to a text string using lxml:

```
el = etree.Element("someelement")
el.text = 'Disponible Ã  partir du 1er Octobre'
```

I get the error:

> ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no
>   NULL bytes or control characters

I've also tried:

```
el.ext = etree.CDATA('Disponible Ã  partir du 1er Octobre')
```

However I get the same error.

How do I handle French in XML, in particular, ISO-8859-1?  There are ways to specify encoding within the tostring() function in lxml, but not for assigning text values within elements.

Comment: el.text = etree.CDATA(('Disponible Ã  partir du 1er Octobre').decode('utf-8')) or el.text = ('Disponible Ã  partir du 1er Octobre').decode('utf-8')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If text contains non-ascii data then you should provide it as a Unicode string for `el.text`.

As [@Abbasov Alexander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17138100/4279) shows you could do it using a Unicode literal `u''`. Python hasn't raise an exception so I assume that you've declared a character encoding of your Python source file (e.g., using `# coding: utf-8` comment at the top). This encoding defines how Python interprets non-ascii characters in the source, it is unrelated to the encoding you use to save xml to a file.

If the text is already in a variable and you haven't converted it to Unicode yet, you could do it using `text.decode(text_encoding)` (`text_encoding` may be unrelated to the Python source encoding).

The confusing bit might be that `el.text` (as an optimization) returns a bytestring on Python 2 for pure ascii data. It breaks the rule that you should not mix bytes and Unicode strings. Though It should work if `sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns an ascii-based encoding as it does in most cases.

To save xml, pass any character encoding you need to`tostring()` or `ElementTree.write()` functions. Again, this encoding is unrelated to others already mentioned encodings.

In general, use [Unicode sandwich](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html#35): decode bytes to Unicode as soon as you receive them, work with Unicode text inside your program, encode to bytes as late as possible when you need to send the text using API that doesn't support Unicode (files, network).

Comment: Ins't it a slightly confusing error message? The user is actually supplying Unicode UTF-8 and it says it should be either Unicode or Ascii. I think it would have been more clear if it says - Input should be of type 'unicode' or 'str' with ascii characters (or no non-ascii characters).

Comment: @Nishant: I agree. You could suggest a better wording on lxml's issue tracker. Though, on Python 3, it is `str` and `bytes` types correspondingly. If it is not clear from the answer; my recommendation: always use Unicode (`unicode` on Python 2, `str` on Python 3), to represent text. Do not use the confusing `bytes` optimization for ASCII text. Anyway, in the recent Python versions, Unicode strings that contain only ascii do not consume much more memory (due to the flexible representation of Unicode strings in Python 3.3+) i.e., the optimization makes even less sense.

Answer (score 5):

If you have version of python < 3 you can try:
`el.text = u'Disponible Ã  partir du 1er Octobre'`