# Python-LXML : ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, lxml

When trying to generate a xml using python code I get this error:

> ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters.

Please help in completing my code. I basically have two questions.

First code : Open python IDLE

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-

def generatexmlfile():
        from lxml import etree as ET            
        page = ET.Element('Module')
        ET.tostring(page, xml_declaration=True)
        doc = ET.ElementTree(page)
        #headElt = ET.SubElement(page, 'head')
        headElt = ET.SubElement(page, 'TestCaseName', NAME="118_Function Sinitiation ", TCID="118", AUTOMATIONID="118_01")
        title = ET.SubElement(headElt, 'PAYMENT_value')
        input_string='Suspended|€ 2,000.00'        
        cleaned_string = ''.join(c for c in input_string if valid_xml_char_ordinal(c))
        title.text = cleaned_string              
        outFile = open('D:\\python\\CreateXML\\homemade.xml', 'w')
        doc.write(outFile,xml_declaration=True,encoding='utf-8',method="xml")

def valid_xml_char_ordinal(c):
    codepoint = ord(c)
    # conditions ordered by presumed frequency
    return (
        0x20 <= codepoint <= 0xD7FF or
        codepoint in (0x9, 0xA, 0xD) or
        0xE000 <= codepoint <= 0xFFFD or
        0x10000 <= codepoint <= 0x10FFFF
        )

generatexmlfile()
```

The questions are:

1. The IDLE does not allow me to save unless `# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-` is added. what is `# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-` ?
2. The € character in the code causes the problem. Please let me know how to handle it and complete the xml generation

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/17138088/407651. Try this: `input_string  = u'Suspended|€ 2,000.00'`.

Comment: Thanks @mzjn , it worked for me and removed valid_xml_char_ordinal(c) method

Comment: @mzjn can you help in converting the value in input_string  to unicode?

Comment: What is the problem? Doesn't `input_string = u'Suspended|€ 2,000.00'` work?

Comment: @mzjn, I m trying to insert value using dictionary which is appended from  excel file . The excel file might contain string with non ascii value or might not. I trying to handle such scenarios . Pleae help

Comment: I think you should ask a new question. Make sure to provide a [mcve].