# Python LXML- Method to check if the variable value has non ASCII value, if yes return unicode value

Tags: python, xml, unicode, lxml, python-unicode

I am trying to create xml in python using LXML . The value of a variable from a external data source is used to enter value in my xml file. if the value of variable contains non ASCII charector like € , that results in

```
ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters.
```

Question : I want a method in python that would check if value in the variable contains non ASCII value , if yes , return corresponding unicode value for that variable , so that I can use the same for my xml?
I am not looking for input_string = u'string €'. As I told, the variable gets its value from external data source. Please help

Comment: it's not a problem of non ASCII symbols in a string. Exception says that you have NULL bytes or control characters in string.

Comment: When I remove the € , it works fine. This is a continuation of the question   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46870889/python-lxml-valueerror-all-strings-must-be-xml-compatible?noredirect=1#comment80701527_46870889

Comment: Hmm. As it follows from your comment below your 1st question, convertation your input to unicode fixes the `ValueError`. So do you have `input_string = u'string €'` or just `input_string = 'string €'` in the case it throws the `ValueError`? And what is a type of value you get from external data source?

Comment: @MaximTitarenko, I pull data from an excel in the variable input_string and it contains value  'string €'. I want to convert the value in variable to unicode.  Setting input_string = u'string €' is out of the scene now. Let us talk only about how to convert non ascii value in a variable to unicode

Comment: @Dani, do you use Python 2.7?

Comment: @MaximTitarenko yes i do use python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're looking for this:
*(assume Python 2.7 and input data of `<type 'str'>`)*

```
# function that converts input_string from 'str' to 'unicode'
# only if input_string contains non-ASCII bytes 

def decode_if_no_ascii(input_string):

    try:
        input_string.decode('ascii')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        input_string = input_string.decode('utf-8') # 'utf-8' should match the encoding of input_string,
                                                    # it could be 'latin_1' or 'cp1252' in a particular case            
    return input_string
```

Let's test the function:

```
# 1. ASCII str
input_string = 'string' 
input_string = decode_if_no_ascii(input_string)
print type(input_string), repr(input_string), input_string
# <type 'str'> 'string' string  
# ==> still 'str', no changes 

# 2. non-ASCII str
input_string = 'string €'
input_string = decode_if_no_ascii(input_string)
print type(input_string), repr(input_string), input_string
# <type 'unicode'> u'string \u20ac' string € 
# ==> converted to 'unicode'
```

Is this what are you looking for?

Comment: I tried your code and i get  error  in Python IDLE 2.7.9. Before saving the code, the system asks me to edit the code with # -*- coding: cp1252 -*- , Though adding it I get the error                                                  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 7: invalid start byte

Comment: @Dani, then your input data should be in `cp1252`. Try to decode with `cp1252` instead `utf-8` in the function

Comment: Actually, in `cp1252` the `0x80` byte is `EURO SIGN`

Comment: you are awesome man. hell of a solution... Thank you very much